# Function that concatenates two pointer strings together

Tags: c, pointers

I am having issues when it comes to concatenating these two pointer strings together, below is my concatenating function, I am supposed to take string 1 and add it to string 2. Also I cannot use any functions in the string library, that's the point of this is to help us understand what code is actually in the functions by writing it ourself.

```
char strconcat(char *user2p, char *user1p) {
    while (*user2p) {
        user2p++;
    }
    while (*user1p) {
        *user2p = *user1p;
        *user2p++;
        *user1p++;
    }
    *user2p = '\0';

    printf("test: %c", *user2p);

    return *user2p;
}
```

And here is the part of my main that is relevant to the function.

```
int main() {
    char userString1[21], userString2[21];
    char *user1p, *user2p;

    user1p = userString1;
    user2p = userString2;

    printf("Please enter the first string: ");
    gets(userString1);

    printf("Please enter the second string: ");
    gets(userString2);

    printf("String 1 after concatenation: ");
    puts(userString1);
    printf("String 2 after concatenation: %c\n", strconcat(user2p, user1p));
```

The terminal keeps giving me this, I didn't include the code for the length and alphabetical order. It gives me a null when I try to run the test `printf` in the function and it gives me nothing when I return the function. I'm at a loss and any help is much appreciated!

```
 Please enter the first string: jackhammer
 Please enter the second string: jacky
 The length of string 1 is: 10
 The length of string 2 is: 5
 String 1 comes before string 2 alphabetically.
 String 1 after concatenation: jackhammer
 (null)
 String 2 after concatenation:
```

Comment: You seem to not really understand pointers yet. `return *user2p;` returns a single char, namely the `'\0'` you just assigned 4 lines above.

Comment: `strconcat` will return 0; I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: Do you have any guarantee that the string to extend is followed by sufficient accessable and useable memory?

Comment: @Yunnosch, yes, it is dangerous. So is the standard library's `strcat()`.  OP is obviously a novice, and obviously has an assignment. Relax.

Answer (score 5):

Your concat algorithm is fine, but you have to return a *pointer* to the *original* [leftmost] value, so your function needs to save it before looping:

```
char *
strconcat(char *user2p, char *user1p)
{
    char *orig2p = user2p;

    while (*user2p) {
        user2p++;
    }
    while (*user1p) {
        *user2p = *user1p;
        user2p++;
        user1p++;
    }
    *user2p = '\0';

    printf("test: %s\n", orig2p);

    return orig2p;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

To come up with a completely bulletproof test program for the concat function, we can use [overly] large input buffers and clip the input length to a maximum of 1/2 of the target buffer.

`gets` *strips* the newline but `fgets` does *not*. So, I've created an `xgets` function that is similar to `gets` but uses `fgets` and `strchr` to get [nearly] the same effect.

Although I believe it's okay to use standard string functions as part of the *test* code, I've created a hand coded version of `strchr` [hope that's not your next assignment :-)].

Anyway, here's the full program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *
strconcat(char *user2p, char *user1p)
{
    char *orig2p = user2p;

    while (*user2p) {
        user2p++;
    }
    while (*user1p) {
        *user2p = *user1p;
        *user2p++;
        *user1p++;
    }
    *user2p = '\0';

    printf("test: %s\n", orig2p);

    return orig2p;
}

char *
xstrchr(char *buf,int chrwant)
{
    int chrcur;
    char *res = NULL;

    for (chrcur = *buf++;  chrcur != 0;  chrcur = *buf++) {
        if (chrcur == chrwant) {
            res = buf - 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    return res;
}

char *
xgets(char *buf,int maxlen)
{
    char *cp;
    char *res;

    res = fgets(buf,maxlen,stdin);

    if (res != NULL) {
        cp = xstrchr(buf,'\n');
        if (cp != NULL)
            *cp = 0;
    }

    return res;
}

#define MAXLEN      800

int
main(void)
{
    char userString1[MAXLEN], userString2[MAXLEN + 1];
    char *user1p, *user2p;

    printf("Please enter the first string: ");
    user1p = xgets(userString1,MAXLEN / 2);

    printf("Please enter the second string: ");
    user2p = xgets(userString2,MAXLEN / 2);

    if ((user2p != NULL) && (user1p != NULL))
        printf("String 2 after concatenation: %s\n",strconcat(user2p, user1p));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the assumption based on, that user2p is followed by sufficient memory? I do not get that part. If it is not clarified, the code looks like writing beyond...

Comment: And that solves the problem in which way? As used neither the shown code nor any similar acting code can safely be used. Assumptions on allocation of local variables ( `userString1` and `userString2`)  are a risky business.

Comment: Lets hope the judge/teacher/reviewer is of your opinion. Or this answer will turn out to be an evil trap.

Comment: Is this logic correct? What is *user2p++ and *user1p++? Shouldn't be user2p++ and user1p++?

Comment: @Yunnosch Per OP: _Also I cannot use any functions in the string library, that's the point of this is to help us understand what code is actually in the functions by writing it ourself._ So, `strcat` does no checking, so the idea is to just implement code that does exactly what `strcat` does. That is, it no more or less risky than using native `strcat`

Comment: @GovindParmar I got that. My only question is why do we need to do that?

Comment: @kadina Good catch. You are correct, but it is harmless [just an extra fetch]. I'll fix it.

Comment: @GovindParmar Craig noticed it. I am asking why do we need to that when we have to increment only addresses.

Comment: Thanks @CraigEstey

Comment: @CraigEstey Thank you! Great for the most part it works, the test `printf` in the function prints it out correctly, but when it's returned the terminal reads out a `?`, What is the problem with my `printf` in the main? It's `printf("String 2 after concatenation: %c\n", strconcat(user2p, user1p));` If I change the `%c` to `%s` it gives me a `segmentation fault 11`

Comment: Changing `%c` to `%s` is the correct fix. As others have mentioned, you have to be careful to not exceed the string lengths. (i.e. `userString2` has to be large enough to take the combined length of both strings). This _isn't_ a concat function problem. So, if each string were (e.g.) 12 chars long, `userString2` isn't large enough. The simple solution is to do (e.g. `char userString2[800]`). The target space has to be [at least] `strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1`. As a side note, consider using `fgets` instead of `gets` [which is deprecated]. It's a bit more work, but has more safety.

Answer (score 2):

There's a number of issues. First is this.

```
while (*user1p) {
    *user2p = *user1p;
    *user2p++;
    *user1p++;
}
```

This is working by accident. If you have compiler warnings on you should get a warning...

```
test.c:13:9: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        *user2p++;
        ^~~~~
test.c:14:9: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        *user1p++;
        ^~~~~~~
```

The reason it's unused is because C is interpreting it like so:

```
*(user1p++)
```

Increment the pointer, then dereference it. You just want to increment the pointers, no dereferencing required.

```
while (*user1p) {
    *user2p = *user1p;
    user2p++;
    user1p++;
}
```

---

Then down here.

```
printf("String 2 after concatenation: %c\n", strconcat(user2p, user1p));
```

`%c` prints an individual `char`. You want `%s` which prints a `char *`. This reveals you have the wrong signature. `strconcat` should return a `char *` (ie. what C uses for strings) and return `user2p` (a `char *`).

```
char *strconcat(char *orig_to, const char *from) {
    ...

    return user2p;
}
```

And since you're not changing `from` it should be `const char *` to let the compiler know and warn you if its accidentally changed.

---

Finally, when you return `*user2p` it's already been moved to the end of the string.

```
while (*user1p) {
    *user2p = *user1p;
    user2p++;
    user1p++;
}
*user2p = '\0';

printf("test: %c", *user2p);

// This points to the null byte just set above
return user2p;
```

So printing the result of `strconcat` will print nothing. To get around this, store the original pointer for `user2p` and return that.

```
char *strconcat(char *orig_to, const char *from) {
    char *orig_user2p = user2p;

    ...

    return orig_user2p;
}
```

---

And some tips. It's easier to follow the code with good variable names that describe what they're doing.

```
char *strconcat(char *orig_to, const char *from) {
    char *to = orig_to;
    ...
}
```

`char foo[NN]` already makes `foo` a pointer. There's no need to declare separate `char *` variables and copy the pointer.

```
char from[21], to[21];
```

Never use `gets`. There's no limit to how much memory it can use and it can easily overflow your buffer. Use `fgets` which can limit how much can be read to available memory.

```
printf("Please enter the string to concat from: ");
fgets(from, sizeof(from), stdin);
```

Though it's annoying that it keeps the newline and there's no simple function to strip it. You can use `scanf` which will strip whitespace, but [beware its many pitfalls](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html).

```
printf("Please enter the string to concat from: ");
scanf("%20s", from);

printf("Please enter the string to concat to: ");
scanf("%20s", to);
```

Finally, be sure the string you're concatenating to can hold its own contents and the new contents.

```
char from[21], to[41];

printf("Please enter the string to concat to: ");
// Be sure to leave enough room in `to` to fit `from`.
fgets(to, sizeof(to) - sizeof(from), stdin);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have created a more dynamic memory model. This code is more generic and concatenates strings creating a new string containing both strings.. Free when done :-)...

```
char *strconcat(char *string1, char *string2) {
    int lenStr1=0,lenStr2=0;
    char *tmpStr1=string1,*tmpStr2=string2,*returnStr;
    while (*tmpStr1++)lenStr1++;
    while (*tmpStr2++)lenStr2++;
    if((returnStr=(char *)malloc(lenStr1+lenStr2+1))){
        memcpy(returnStr,string1,lenStr1);
        memcpy(&returnStr[lenStr1],string2,lenStr2);
        returnStr[lenStr1+lenStr2]=0;
        return returnStr;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    char *string1="String 1 ",*string2="String 2 ",*result;
    if((result=strconcat(string1, string2))) {
        printf("-> %s \n",result);
        free(result);
    } else {
        printf("Out of memory");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```